# Line number of system call affects python WindowsError: [Error 126]

Tags: python, c++

I have a very strange problem. I have a project that relies on a Python script as the last "step" of sorts, before the program finishes. To do this, I figured a `system()` would be adequate, despite its bad reputation for security. Below will best demonstrate the issue:

Not working, and the way in which I need it to work:

```
/*Script produces traceback, but this is how I need it*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ...Lots of code...
  string path_to_python_script = ....
  system(path_to_python_script);
}
```

But ridiculously, this works:

```
/*Script works here, but would break my program*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  string path_to_python_script = ....
  system(path_to_python_script);
  ..lots of code...
}
```

The location of the `system()` calls above is the only thing that changes. The `lots of code` in my program does not change the file system in any way.

The traceback, caused by an inability to find a `.pynative` folder, although it finds it just fine in the above example that works. :

```
File "./ocropus-gpageseg", line 22, in <module>
import ocrolib
File "C:\Users\...\ocrolib\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from common import *
File "C:\Users\...\ocrolib\common.py", line 18, in <module>
import lstm
File "C:\Users\...\ocrolib\lstm.py", line 32, in <module>
import nutils
File "C:\Users\...\ocrolib\nutils.py", line 25, in <module>
lstm_native = compile_and_load(lstm_utils)
File "C:\Users\...\ocrolib\native.py", line 68, in compile_and_load
return ctypes.CDLL(path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: There's a good chance you've got undefined behaviour in the "`lots of code`" part which you're _not_ showing us. I recommend hunting it down by commenting out different bits of that code, or using a tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Hmm, perhaps. It's an openCV project. It works fantastically on Linux, this is me "porting" it to windows. So you think UB could cause a python error like that?

Comment: It could be that something damages the environment in which the python script then gets called. That could result in python's search paths being different. Or maybe you're just in a different working directory? Hard to say without seeing more of the code. A [mcve] is usually a good idea.

Comment: Hmm.. I just dug through the python library I am working with and hard coded the path to the `.pynative` folder, and it worked. Don't `system` calls use the same working directory as the program executable? I'm afraid this problem is a little convoluted.

Comment: Again, it's hard to say what part of the environment might have changed before `system` is called, without seeing the code. But your `system` call is perfectly fine, so the code leading up to it must be the culprit.

Comment: I'll do my best to investigate, for clarity at least